# Problem with fragment and buttons in my android app

Tags: java, android, android-imagebutton

So, I recently started with android coding. I don't know if I'm asking this question in the right forum or in the right way. I am new to coding and to forums. So forgive me if I'm not doing this the right way.

This code worked when I used it in the MainActivity but then the buttons showed on all of the pages, now i only want it to show on one page which is the 'main fragment'.

Forgive me but I don't really know the difference between an activity and a fragment, maybe it's a big difference in code, maybe not.

I am trying to add 2 different buttons to my app, the buttons show but when I press them nothing happens.
It's probably a really ridiculous problem but for me it is not clear. I have been trying to search for a solution but I don't know what to search for.

Thank you.

This is my trash code.

```
package com.example.snuskappen;
import android.content.Intent;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageButton;

import com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.navigation.NavController;
import androidx.navigation.Navigation;
import androidx.navigation.ui.AppBarConfiguration;
import androidx.navigation.ui.NavigationUI;

public class home extends AppCompatActivity {

    //   ImageButton grKnapp;
    //   ImageButton generalKnapp;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.fragment_home);
        BottomNavigationView navView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        // Passing each menu ID as a set of Ids because each
        // menu should be considered as top level destinations.
        AppBarConfiguration appBarConfiguration = new AppBarConfiguration.Builder(
                R.id.navigation_home, R.id.navigation_dashboard, R.id.navigation_notifications)
                .build();
        NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment);
        NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController, appBarConfiguration);
        NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(navView, navController);


        ImageButton grKnapp = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.grKnapp);
        ImageButton generalKnapp = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.generalKnapp);

        grKnapp.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent int1 = new Intent(home.this, grActivity.class);
                startActivity(int1);
            }


        });


         generalKnapp.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
             @Override
             public void onClick(View v) {
                 Intent int2 = new Intent(home.this,general.class);
                 startActivity(int2);
             }
         });
    }
    }
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ui.home.HomeFragment">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_home"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/grKnapp"
        android:layout_width="110dp"
        android:layout_height="110dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:src="@tools:sample/backgrounds/scenic" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/generalKnapp"
        android:layout_width="110dp"
        android:layout_height="110dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.055"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/grKnapp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:src="@tools:sample/backgrounds/scenic" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: can you add `Toast` messages in `ImageButton` callbacks and tell if they are shown? if yes, then please provide `general.class` & `grActivity.class` code

Comment: The Toast message is not showing either.